# Migrating Limesurvey Community to Cloud Solution

Tags: migration, cloud, limesurvey

I'm using a self-hosted Limesurvey community edition instance. I probably will buy the cloud-hosted solution, so, is there an easy way to migrate the data that exists in the database?

I couldn't find any documentation about it, but if I can't get an easier solution, I will use the LimeSurvey API (remote control) to map the data from the self-hosted version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

They have a migration service which is included if you buy a LimeSurvey Cloud **Expert** plan or higher. Just buy the plan, zip up the files and create a database dump and send it to their support. Usually they migrate it within 24 hours.